# Selecting one distinct column, I.E Finetuning select query

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I use the bellow query to merge 1 (or possibly sevral tables and is generated from a php script I have written) on Id's that are not the same but parts of Id in first table is part of the second Id so thats why I do a Substring on it. In the most perfect world I would just left join on id in both tables if there were the same but they're not.

```
select t0.Id,t0.CustomerName,t0.Region,t0.Country,t0.StopTime,t0.CustomerId,t1.Id, t1.Time
from (select distinct Id,CustomerName,Region,Country, StopTime,CustomerId from [dbcust].[dbo].[_Content]) t0 
Inner JOIN 
(select distinct Id, Time from [dbcust].[dbo].[_Cpu]) t1 
        on SUBSTRING(t1.Id,CHARINDEX('_',t1.Id,10)+1,(CHARINDEX('_',t1.Id,15) - CHARINDEX('_',t1.Id,10)-1))=SUBSTRING(t0.Id,CHARINDEX('_',t0.Id,10)+1,(CHARINDEX('_',t0.Id,15) - CHARINDEX('_',t0.Id,10)-1)) ORDER BY t1.Time DESC
```

Here I get Alot of fields that are the same except for StopTime, see example bellow:

```
       StopTime                   Time
2015-04-01 23:59:00.000    2015-04-18 23:00:01
2015-04-02 23:59:00.000    2015-04-18 23:00:01
2015-04-03 23:59:00.000    2015-04-18 23:00:01
2015-04-04 23:59:00.000    2015-04-18 23:00:01
2015-04-05 23:59:00.000    2015-04-18 23:00:01
2015-04-06 23:59:00.000    2015-04-18 23:00:01
2015-04-07 23:59:00.000    2015-04-18 23:00:01
2015-04-08 23:59:00.000    2015-04-18 23:00:01
2015-04-09 23:59:00.000    2015-04-18 23:00:01
2015-04-10 23:59:00.000    2015-04-18 23:00:01
2015-04-11 23:59:00.000    2015-04-18 23:00:01
2015-04-12 23:59:00.000    2015-04-18 23:00:01
2015-04-13 23:59:00.000    2015-04-18 23:00:01
2015-04-14 23:59:00.000    2015-04-18 23:00:01
2015-04-15 23:59:00.000    2015-04-18 23:00:01
2015-04-16 23:59:00.000    2015-04-18 23:00:01
2015-04-17 23:59:00.000    2015-04-18 23:00:01
2015-04-18 23:59:00.000    2015-04-18 23:00:01
```

But here I only want unique Time, is it possible to get a row with the unique Time and the latest StopTime?

Like the bellow?

```
        StopTime                   Time
2015-04-01 23:59:00.000    2015-04-18 23:00:01
```

I tried with a `group by` statement inside the second select statement like:

```
(select distinct Id,CustomerName,Region,Country, StopTime,CustomerId from [dbcust].[dbo].[_Content] group by StopTime)
```

But I get a syntax error

> Column 'dbcust.dbo._Content.Id' is invalid in the select list because
>   it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

Perhaps you guys can help me with finetuning my select query in order to speed up the data gathering? =)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
WITH YourQuery
AS
(
    select t0.Id,t0.CustomerName,t0.Region,t0.Country,t0.StopTime,t0.CustomerId,t1.Id, t1.Time
    from (select distinct Id,CustomerName,Region,Country, StopTime,CustomerId from [dbcust].[dbo].[_Content]) t0 
    Inner JOIN 
    (select distinct Id, Time from [dbcust].[dbo].[_Cpu]) t1 
            on SUBSTRING(t1.Id,CHARINDEX('_',t1.Id,10)+1,(CHARINDEX('_',t1.Id,15) - CHARINDEX('_',t1.Id,10)-1))=SUBSTRING(t0.Id,CHARINDEX('_',t0.Id,10)+1,(CHARINDEX('_',t0.Id,15) - CHARINDEX('_',t0.Id,10)-1)) 
), Ranked
AS
(
   select Id,
     CustomerName,
     Region,
     Country,
     StopTime,
     CustomerId,
     Id, 
     Time,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Time ORDER BY StopTime DESC) AS R1
    from  YourQuery
)
SELECT Id,
     CustomerName,
     Region,
     Country,
     StopTime,
     CustomerId,
     Id, 
     Time
FROM Ranked
WHERE RN = 1;
```

The [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function will give a ranking number for each `time`, so selecting `where rn = 1` will give you the latest `stoptime`.

---

For the query you tried:

```
select distinct Id,CustomerName,Region,Country, 
   StopTime,CustomerId 
from [dbcust].[dbo].[_Content] 
group by StopTime
```

In sql server, when you `group by` a column, you can't select any column unless it is in the group by clause or in an aggregate function, so in order to write it correctly it should be like this:

```
select stopTime, MIN(CustomerId) -- just an example
from [dbcust].[dbo].[_Content] 
group by StopTime
```

Or using your full query you can do this:

```
SELECT stoptime, MAX(Time) AS LatestTime
FROM
(
    select t0.Id,t0.CustomerName,t0.Region,t0.Country,t0.StopTime,t0.CustomerId,t1.Id, t1.Time
            from (select distinct Id,CustomerName,Region,Country, StopTime,CustomerId from [dbcust].[dbo].[_Content]) t0 
            Inner JOIN 
            (select distinct Id, Time from [dbcust].[dbo].[_Cpu]) t1 
                    on SUBSTRING(t1.Id,CHARINDEX('_',t1.Id,10)+1,(CHARINDEX('_',t1.Id,15) - CHARINDEX('_',t1.Id,10)-1))=SUBSTRING(t0.Id,CHARINDEX('_',t0.Id,10)+1,(CHARINDEX('_',t0.Id,15) - CHARINDEX('_',t0.Id,10)-1)) 
) AS t
GROUP BY stoptime
```

This will give you the exact result that you are looking for, but only the `stoptime` and the latest time.

So to select the other columns as will as the two columns I used the ranking function.